# Here Maps - mapView.getCamera().lookAt() Method does update MapView

Tags: android, react-native, here-api

I creating React Native UI Component for Here Maps API. The problem I am facing is the Map gets loaded but does update the loaded MapView with coordinates which are set using mapView.getCamera().lookAt() method. The approach I am following is to load the MapView inside the fragment which the I use to render the map.

Here Maps SDK - Explore Edition

**HereMapFragment.java**

```
public class HereMapFragment extends Fragment {

  private MapViewProperties mapViewProperties;

  public HereMapFragment(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    this.context = reactContext;
    mapViewProperties = new MapViewProperties();
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
    ConstraintLayout frameLayout = (ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, null);
    return frameLayout;
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    this.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadMapScene();

  }

  private void loadMapScene() {
    this.mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapScheme.NORMAL_DAY, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapError mapError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "on loadscene called.");
        if (mapError == null) {
          mapView.getMapScene().setLayerVisibility(MapScene.Layers.LANDMARKS, VisibilityState.VISIBLE);
          Log.e(TAG, Double.toString(mapViewProperties.getCurrentCoordinates().latitude)); //This prints correct coordinates
          Log.e(TAG, Double.toString(mapViewProperties.getCurrentCoordinates().longitude));
          mapView.getCamera().lookAt(mapViewProperties.getCurrentCoordinates());
          // searchExample = new SearchExample(context, mapView);
        } else {
          Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + mapError.toString());
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public void setCurrentCoordinates(GeoCoordinates currentCoordinates) {
    mapViewProperties.setCurrentCoordinates(currentCoordinates);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
  }

}
```

**HereMapsViewManager.java**

```
public class HereMapsViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<ConstraintLayout> {

  private Fragment fragment;

  @Override
  public ConstraintLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    final ConstraintLayout view = new ConstraintLayout(context);
    fragment = new HereMapFragment(reactContext);
    reactContext.getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(fragment, "My_TAG")
        .commit();
    reactContext.getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    addView(view, fragment.getView(), 0);
    return view;

  }

  @ReactProp(name = "defaultMarker")
  public void setDefaultMarker(ConstraintLayout view, ReadableMap readableMap) {
    MapView mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
   
    Log.e(TAG, Double.toString(readableMap.getDouble("latitude")));
    ((HereMapFragment) fragment).setCurrentCoordinates(
        new GeoCoordinates(readableMap.getDouble("latitude"), readableMap.getDouble("longitude")));
  }
}
```

**map_fragment.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.here.sdk.mapview.MapView android:id="@+id/map_view" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.here.sdk.mapview.MapView>
    <LinearLayout app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/search_id" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Search" />
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Geocoding" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Logs**

```
07-05 20:49:18.500  9606  9937 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
07-05 20:49:18.588  9606  9606 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Render loop thread resumed
07-05 20:49:18.588  9606  9606 W harp-sdk: [WARN ] harp-sdk - View config is empty. No map content will be displayed until valid config is provided.
07-05 20:49:18.589  9606  9606 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding renderable
07-05 20:49:18.589  9606  9606 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
07-05 20:49:18.590  9606  9606 I chatty  : uid=10163(com.amazon.sft.rangoli.seller.app) identical 6 lines
07-05 20:49:18.590  9606  9606 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
07-05 20:49:18.594  9606  9937 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Skip applying configuration with empty filename.
07-05 20:49:18.594  9606  9937 W harp-sdk: [WARN ] harp-sdk - Invalid render target at initialization time.
07-05 20:49:18.594  9606  9937 W harp-sdk: [WARN ] harp-sdk - Invalid map configuration at initialization time.
07-05 20:49:18.594  9606  9937 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Renderable added
07-05 20:49:18.595  9606  9937 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
07-05 20:49:18.595  9606  9937 I harp-sdk: [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
```

The coordinates I am trying to load are 28.7041° N, 77.1025° E but the default location is loading. It would be really helpful if someone can help with the issue.

Comment: Try to call lookAt() in the onReady event. It may happen, that the map was not ready yet due to ReactNative: 
    
    mapView.setOnReadyListener(new MapView.OnReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapViewReady() { mapView.getCamera().lookAt(mapViewProperties.getCurrentCoordinates()); }});

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below steps, which tells how to build a React component that displays the map and responds to the actions of the user, be it direct interaction with the map or the other components.

Setup
For the fast setup of the new React application we will use the [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) environment. It provides a fast way to get started building a new single-page application. Execute the npx runner as below (it requires Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6)

npx create-react-app jsapi-react && cd jsapi-react

The call above produces the scaffolding needed to start the application. The directory structure in the jsapi-react directory looks as follows. The React components reside in the src directory:

my-app
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   ├── ...
└── src
├── App.css
├── App.js
├── App.test.js
├── index.css
├── index.js
├── logo.svg
└── serviceWorker.js
└── setupTests.js

After that the package from the @here namespace can be installed as usual:

npm install @here/maps-api-for-javascript --save

At this step the environment setup is complete, all packages needed to build a sample application are installed, and it is possible to start the development server by executing:

npm start

The command above launches the development server with the "hot reload" functionality and opens the application in the browser.

Add a static map component

It is possible to add a static map to the application by creating a component that contains an H.Map instance and renders it to the component's container. In order to do that create a file Map.js in the src directory for the new React class component. This component displays a map in the container that has a width and a height of 300 pixels:

import React from 'react';
import H from "@here/maps-api-for-javascript";

export default class Map extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
// the reference to the container
this.ref = React.createRef();
// reference to the map
this.map = null;
}

componentDidMount() {
if (!this.map) {
// instantiate a platform, default layers and a map as usual
const platform = new H.service.Platform({
apikey: '{YOUR_API_KEY}'
});
const layers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
const map = new H.Map(
this.ref.current,
layers.vector.normal.map,
{
pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
zoom: 2,
},
);
this.map = map;
}
}

render() {
return (
<div
style={{ width: '300px', height:'300px' }}
ref={this.ref}
/>
)
}
}

The component above now can be used within the App component, replace the content of th src/App.js with the following code:

import Map from './Map';

function App() {
return (



);
}

export default App;

That will render the static map at the zoom level 2 and 0 latitude and longitude:

You can check the same in [React Document Link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.32.0/dev_guide/topics/react-practices.html)

Comment: Oh hello there chat GPT